# c )make error& link problem: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file, incompatible with i386 output

Tags: c, makefile, compiler-errors, linker-errors, incompatibletypeerror

I have this output with error message when i type "make" in terminal!!

```
gcc test1.o dispatchQueue.o -o test1 -pthread
/usr/bin/ld: i386:x86-64 architecture of input file `test1.o' is incompatible with i386     output
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test1] Error 1
```

Is there anyone who can explain why and how to fix it? :(

I'm attaching makefile just in case

```
# Comment out the targets you don't want.

# Runs all of the tests.
all: test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 testFor
    ./test1
    ./test2
    ./test3
    ./test4
    ./test5
    ./testFor

test1: test1.o dispatchQueue.o
    gcc test1.o dispatchQueue.o -o test1 -pthread

test1.o: test1.c
    gcc -c test1.c

test2: test2.o dispatchQueue.o
    gcc test2.o dispatchQueue.o -o test2 -pthread

test2.o: test2.c
    gcc -c test2.c

test3: test3.o dispatchQueue.o
    gcc test3.o dispatchQueue.o -o test3 -pthread

test3.o: test3.c
    gcc -c test3.c

test4: test4.o dispatchQueue.o
    gcc test4.o dispatchQueue.o -o test4 -pthread

test4.o: test4.c
    gcc -c test4.c

test5: test5.o dispatchQueue.o
    gcc test5.o dispatchQueue.o -o test5 -pthread

test5.o: test5.c
    gcc -c test5.c

testFor: testFor.o dispatchQueue.o
    gcc testFor.o dispatchQueue.o -o testFor -pthread

testFor.o: testFor.c
    gcc -c testFor.c

dispatchQueue.o: dispatchQueue.c dispatchQueue.h
    gcc -c dispatchQueue.c
```

Comment: Paste the Makefile. But the problem, as it is telling you, is that some of the files have been compiled (implicitly or explicitly with `-m64`) while the link target (and possibly other object files) are handled with `-m32`.

Comment: The Makefile looks fine (except you should really use the `-pthread` switch on everyfile). Perhaps you've moved the project from another machine, have you tried removing the object files and recompiling?

Comment: Hm.. no.. I actually tried this at uni and worked fine(actually Makefile is given by the lecturer haha).. hmm how to you remove the object files?

Answer (score 42):

You probably have some old files (at least test1.o) compiled for i386-x64. You can remove these old files and run make again. If you can modify the Makefile try adding a line such as:

```
clean:
    rm *.o test1 test2 test3 test4 test5 testFor
```

Then when you run `make clean` it'll remove the old stuff, at which point you can run make again.

Comment: +1 I just had the same problem and Google brought me here. After running `make clean` it worked :)

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem. Problem for me was that object files were generated with i386 arichitecture and I was trying to link with x86_64 linker. I deleted object files generated them anew with x86_64 options and tried to linking again. It works now

Answer (score 2):

If the makefile is generated for the system, you should run ./configure to get new ones, and then recompile.